# Monitor Tile with Data from HCP (js)

Tags: sapui5

I'm currently testing Web-IDE and try to create a small app with a tile which automatically updates itself with data from HCP.

Is TileContainer the right function to create this ? I'm not sure which Tile I have to use.

How do I feed the Data into the content of the tile ?

```
var tileContainer = new sap.m.TileContainer({
tiles : [ 
new sap.m.StandardTile({
number: "C_SENSORTEMP",
height: "50px",
icon : "sap-icon://play",
title : "Temparature",
frameType: "TwoByOne",
press : function() {
oController._eventHandler("start");
app.to("page2");
})
]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes tile is right way. Here is small example:

```
<GenericTile class="sapUiTinyMarginBegin sapUiTinyMarginTop tileLayout" header="Cumulative Totals" subheader="Expenses" frameType="OneByOne"
    press="press">
    <tileContent>
        <TileContent unit="Unit" footer="Footer Text">
            <content>
                <NumericContent value="12"/>
            </content>
        </TileContent>
    </tileContent>
</GenericTile>
```

[image]

When you want to bind data you can make it in the xml file as:

```
<NumericContent value="{ForExampleExpenses}"/>
```

And in the controller you need to bind oData service:

```
this.getView().bindElement(/getExpenses);
```

You can find more examples [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.GenericTile/samples).

Comment: ok.thanks how would for example the binding of the citytemperature from openweather look like in view.js ? source: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&mode=json

Comment: The link you send does not work for me (401 Authorization Required). But  from json example from that side ((http://openweathermap.org/current) chapter Weather parameters in API respond, JSON, Example of API respond.): "main":{"temp":293.25,... you can try this: <NumericContent value="{main>temp}"/> in the xml.view